# How can I look for the exact text string of a cell within a range of other cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am working with a dataset represented by the example below, filled with chemical compound names. Many of the chemical compound names have similar names, but are not exactly the same.

I am looking for a way to check a list of compounds within a Sample `A2:A5` if there is an exact match in a range `D2:E6`. My current way of doing it is this:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(D2:E6,"*"& A2 &"*"),"Yes","No")
```

However - it does not look for exact matches and counts Grape as a match because of Grapefruit. This is wrong, and I am looking for a way to remove that error.

My example dataset:

[image: My example dataset]

Comment: Although COUNTIF is not case sensitive, it should be exact and not be fuzzy. I am unable to replicate your issue with an example of just grape and grapefruit. I would recommend simplifying your example to include just one cell as I did to confirm the behavior you have described. Begin with just COUNTIF to count the number of instances (remove the quotation marks and the IF). Then add in more complexity as needed.

Comment: If it is a change of a letter at the end of compound, you can replace the wildcard character with "? ". [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amzId.png)

Comment: If you are looking for an exact match you just need to remove the wildcards (*), you have asked it to look for anything containing grape within the word so the function is working exactly as expected if it sees Grapefruit as *Grape* where the first wildcard is nothing and the second is fruit.

Comment: Thanks Justin! That did it.

Answer (score 0):

The wildcards in my 3rd arguement within COUNTIF meant that the search term could have any characters before or after, therefore showing up with non-exact matches. Thank you @Justin Doward for the pointer.